# Hide Jenkins comments in Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I have a Jenkins setup to be triggered by Gerrit once a patch is updated.
I am looking for a way to hide all the messages generated by Jenkins to concentrate on the reviewer's comments.

Messages from Jenkins are something like:

```
Patch Set <id>:
Build Started <url> (1/16)
```

Which pollutes the comment section.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gerrit 2.15 and above it's possible to filter out the Jenkins messages by clicking on "Show Comments Only" button at the change screen.

It's necessary to configure Jenkins to use a tag when adding the message, for example:

```
gerrit review <CHANGE>,<PATCHSET> --message 'Job started <BUILDURL>' --code-review <CODE_REVIEW> --tag 'autogenerated:jenkins'
```

If you're using gerrit-trigger plugin you can configure this at Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Edit

Tagged comments are not shown when "Show Comments Only" are selected.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!